# How to query database to NOT return rows where condition is met

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

```
 myexercise
 id | ex_name | ex_id | owner_id
 1   exercise1    2        1
 2   exercise2    3        1
```

and

```
exercise
id | ex_name
 2   exercise1
 3   exercise2
 4   exercise3
```

I want to write SQL query that return only rows from EXERCISE TABLE where id  isn't  in MYEXERCISE table as ex_id. So it should return only id=>4 and ex_name=>exercise3.
I think it can be done with JOINS but i don't know how.

Comment: What you tried something???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from Exercise
where id not in (select ex_id from myExercise);

select * from Exercise t1
where not exists (select * from myExercise t2 where t1.Id = t2.ex_id);

select * from Exercise t1
left join MyExercise t2 on t1.Id = t2.ex_id
where myExercise.ex_id is null;
```

All these 3 queries would do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `where not exists`

```
select t1.*
from Exercise t1
where not exists (select 1 from MyExercise t2 where t1.ex_id = t2.id)
```

Or a `join`

```
select t1.*
from Exercise t1
left join MyExercise t2
  on t1.ex_id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
    Select *
    from EXERCISE e left join MYEXERCISE me
    ON e.id = ME.id
    Where me.id IS NULL;
```